# How to record rstp source using ffmpeg in own way

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-capture

Is it possible to write videoframes from rtsp source in a own file format desigend as a ring buffer using ffmpeg lib?

Comment: Maybe. What have you tried? How well did it work? How badly didn't it work?

Comment: As I know ffmpeg uses AVFormatContext to write files in a limited list of standart containers. Videodata is closed form user this way.

Comment: I can write avpackets using standart c++ file operation. And I have the outer index file where the size of the packet and its time stamp is stored - so i can read packets from my file, the problem is when I try to decode my file -  I dont know how to initialize AvCodecContext for deodig my packets.